# Reduce array of strings to smallest regexable value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I'm working on a node module that uploads files to s3 and performs a cloudfront invalidation after uploading the files, but considering that invalidation's aren't free I want to reduce the invalidation files paths uploaded to the smallest regexable value possible eg

```
[
  'library-latest-v2.min.js',
  'library-latest-v2.min.js.map',
  'library-latest-v2.test.min.js',
  'library-latest-v2.test.min.js.map'
]
```

Would become `library-latest-v2*`

Any ideas how to go about writing a function to do this? Not having much luck googling. Bonus points if it can handle multiple variations eg

```
[
  'library-latest-v2.min.js',
  'library-latest-v2.min.js.map',
  'other-library-v3.min.js',
  'other-library-v3.min.js.map'
]
```

Would reduce down to `['library-latest-v2*', 'other-library-v3*']` but not sure how possible that would be

Comment: Match everything up to the first `.` and then filter the array for the matching string. If it finds  result remove it and add `*` to the original. If I understand your question that is.

Comment: I would rather go for a `.map` (for replacing `.*` with `*` in the elements), followed by `.uniq`.

Comment: Make sure you match the `.` too otherwise you'd get a possible collision of `v2` and `v23` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Array elements are in given format.

Try something like this.

```js
var arr = [
  'library-latest-v2.min.js',
  'library-latest-v2.min.js.map',
  'other-library-v3.min.js',
  'other-library-v3.min.js.map'
];

var reducedArr = [];
var temp;
arr.forEach(function(item){
   temp = item.split('.')[0] + "*";
   if(reducedArr.indexOf(temp) < 0) reducedArr.push(temp);
});

console.log(reducedArr);
```

And another solution without any further variables

```js
var arr = [
  'library-latest-v2.min.js',
  'library-latest-v2.min.js.map',
  'other-library-v3.min.js',
  'other-library-v3.min.js.map'
].map(function(item){
  return item.split('.')[0] + "*";
}).filter(function(item, index, self){
  return self.indexOf(item) === index;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Like the second solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
let a = [
    'library-latest-v2.min.js',
    'library-latest-v2.min.js.map',
    'other-library-v3.min.js',
    'other-library-v3.min.js.map'
];


let b = [];

for (let i of a) {
    let m = i.match(/[^.]*/).pop() + '*';

    if (b.indexOf(m) === -1) {
        b.push(m);
     }
}
```